# Update multiple fields in SharePoint programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm trying to update some properties on multiple fields (with the same name) in SharePoint.

I've tried this:

```
var site = this.Site.RootWeb;
var fields = site.Fields;

        foreach (SPField field in fields)
        {
            if (field.Group.Contains("My Custom Columns"))
            {
                if (field.Title.Contains("Custom field"))
                {
                    if (field.DefaultValue != null) {
                        field.DefaultValue = null;
                        field.Update(true);
                    }                      
                }
            }
        }
```

It updates the first column with the name "Custom field", but after it's giving me this error:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.  
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection.SPEnumerator.System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext()
```

Is it not possible to Update the object in a foreach loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I believe is with your

```
foreach (SPField field in fields)
```

line of code. You are essentially modifying the collection that you are looping over.

What I would suggest you try is looping and getting the ID's of all the fields in to a

```
List<GUID>
```

Then do a foreach statement on this collection getting each field and updating it's value.

```
List<Guid> guidsList = new List<guid>();
foreach (SPField field in fields)
    {
        if (field.Group.Contains("My Custom Columns"))
        {
            if (field.Title.Contains("Custom field"))
            {
guidsList.add(field.id)

            }
        }
    }

foreach(Guid currentFieldId in guidsList){
//Get your field 
//Update what needs to be updated
}
```

Many Thanks

Truez

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs since you are trying to modify a field collection while iterating it.

The solution would be to replace the line:

```
foreach (SPField field in fields)
```

with

```
foreach (var field in fields.Cast<SPField>().ToList())
```